# JPA QueryDsl subquery can not set offset and limit

Tags: java, jpa, subquery

When I use JPA+QueryDsl, set the limit and offset in subquery can not work

mysql5, spring5, queryDsl4.2.1

```java
pgIdTestEnts =new JPAQueryFactory(em).select(qPgIdTestEnt).from(qPgIdTestEnt)
                .where(
                        qPgIdTestEnt.snowFlakeId.in(
                                new JPAQueryFactory(em).select(qPgIdTestEnt.snowFlakeId).from(qPgIdTestEnt).offset(range.getStart()).limit(range.getLength())
                ))
                .fetch();
```

and I checked logs as follows:

```
select
        pgidtesten0_.SNOW_FLAKE_ID as SNOW_FLA1_0_,
        pgidtesten0_.BATCH_NUMBER as BATCH_NU2_0_ 
    from
        PG_ID_TEST pgidtesten0_ 
    where
        pgidtesten0_.SNOW_FLAKE_ID in (
            select
                pgidtesten1_.SNOW_FLAKE_ID 
            from
                PG_ID_TEST pgidtesten1_
        )
```

the limit and offset aren't shown here, but if I move the limit and offset to the main query, it's ok. so why?

Comment: It's also happening to me, but with *JPAExpressions.select()*

Comment: It has also happened to me. Have you found any solution?